# Web service 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap

I have created web service using c#. I consumed using c# client I got 401  Unauthorized error. So, I set the property UseDefaultCredentials = true.

Then I tried to access the web service using java client, I get again 401  Unauthorized  error. I don't know how to use java client stubs. So, can someone point me in that direction.

I got these class files in Eclipse

```
DemoWebServ.java
DemoWebServLocator.java
DemoWebServSoap.java
DemoWebServSoapProxy.java
DemoWebServSoapStub.java
```

I need to access the web service by giving username and password by using above stubs

**EDIT 1**

on some googling i found that adding

```
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "USERNAME");
    _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "PASSWORD");
```

will solve the issue but even after adding above statements in DemoWebServSoapStub.java. I have not been able to resolve the issue

Comment: Hm, what might these classes look like, if only I could open them...

Comment: @Ridcully : hope my edit answers your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution,

This happened because of the anonymous access security for website in IIS. I used the account I have on the windows server to set anonymous access uname/password. Then I used the same combination in

```
_call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "USERNAME");
_call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "PASSWORD");
```

It worked. I dont know how secure it is :(